# Flash - prompt user to remember camera and mic settings

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, permissions, camera, microphone

I request my user from mic and camera setting on my website with Flash, but the remember checkbox does not show, so every time my user logs in he's requested once again for permissions, how can I make the checkbox show to avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY)` before trying to access the camera.

[Camera Class LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html?filter_flex=4.5&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2.5)

Comment: Do I have to make 2 calls? On for the mic and one for the camera? or the same applies to both?

Comment: This shows the panel but it doesn't pop up on the permissions panel but on the Device/Volume panel

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it should be the `PRIVACY` panel.  I've edited the answer.  It's just 1 call for both camera and mic.

Comment: Read the link in the API and solved, if you simply do this Security.showSettings(); it will prompt to allow and remember the selection, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
var _mic:Microphone;
_mic = Microphone.getMicrophone(<index>);
if(_mic.muted){
    Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
}
```

You can use "muted" property of the microphone instance. You do not need to listen the `StatusEvent.STATUS`. With the code block above, you can ask for permission only once.