# Disable web camera image capture settings popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, flash, webcam

[image: Adobe Flash Player Settings Popup]

How do I disable the above popup in web camera programmatically using asp.net c#?

Comment: Sorry you cant. This is built into Adobe Flash to prevent applications from using the camera \ microphone without their consent. Bypass this allows you to view my webcam when I come to the page. You could even create a blank flash screen and record me programming in my underwear.

Comment: You can ask the user to remember the choice:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516900/flash-prompt-user-to-remember-camera-and-mic-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's a security setting that you can't override.
You will have to use an alternative to Flash player.